# Blu Dash JR K locked-out; "Yes" confirmation option to reset is not present in recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, locked-out

I have my sister's Blu Dash JR K at the moment. She forgot her lock screen pattern, and there is not an option to recover via Gmail.

Phone comes with stock recovery. when I go there and try to apply factory wipe/data, all I get are a bunch of:

```
   -- no --
   -- no --
   -- no --
   -- no --
```

**There is no yes option.**

Second attempt, I tried to reset the phone using ADB, as I don't have the phone with debugging mode active. when I type `adb devices`, no device is detected.

Phone is not rooted so I'm not sure if I can install any custom recovery. What should I do now?

**EDIT**

I'm not able to use "official" recovery modes (Gmail Based) since she never synced with a Google account.

Comment: Hi! I reflected two issues in the title. I think that's OK with you.

Comment: @Firelord sure thing it's better that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share the solution that worked for me in case anyone else runs on the same issue since the documentation for this phone is marginal.

First you need to download the Original ROM, not so hard to find it I don't have the current links else I'll share them.

Then download [SP flash-tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool)

Simply Flash the phone using the tool, I followed this instructions

[Instructions](http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)

Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If your sister has access to Google account, she can try the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and do a "Lock and Erase". You may need to enable Lock and Erase first.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160500

Comment: Is not active, she never setup the google acc. already tried that, i can get into fastboot but can do nothing, i don't actually want to recover info i just want to wipe the phone and start from 0